# What is the purpose of the closure axioms (vector subspaces)?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U \subset V$. If $U$ meets the closure axioms then it's called stabil. My textbook says that it then inherits properties from V. **What which properties?**

Comment: All the properties that a vector space enjoys - the identities that are true for vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: The axioms of a vector space, right?

Comment: I thought that the fact $U$ was a subset $V$ meant that it already inherited these properties... Could anyone give me an example?

Comment: If $V$ contains more than one element, then $U=\{x\}$ for some $0\neq x\in V$ doesn't satisfy that $x+x\in U$, while $V$ does have this property for all its elements.